# How to import a class from a Web Api package

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the project in this structure as shown in the image:

[image]

I can't see the classes that are in the API package of another package outside.
I want load classes of folder ViewModel into API

Comment: That's probably because the API project has dependencies on, and references to, the Data and Domain projects. As a result neither the Data or Domain project can reference the API project - this would be a circular reference and the solution would fail to build.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use classes from one project in another you need to add it as a project reference

[image]

Of course, you can only have this reference one way, otherwise you end up with a circular reference. For example, if API has a reference to Domain, Domain cannot have a reference to API